# When is alternating series in $\mathcal{L}^p$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I want to find out for which $p\geq 1$ we have $u=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}1_{[k,k+1)} \in \mathcal{L}^p$

I have tried the following:
$$\int | \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}1_{[k,k+1)}|^p \, d\lambda$$
$$=\int \bigg(  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1)^k}{k}1_{[k,k+1)}\bigg) ^p  \, d\lambda$$
$$=\int \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}1_{[k,k+1)}  \, d\lambda$$
and because $|u| \in \mathcal{M}^+$, switch integral and sum
$$= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int \frac{1}{k^p}1_{[k,k+1)}  \, d\lambda$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}\cdot 1$$
and so $u \in \mathcal{L}^p$ only for $p>1$ as it is a p-series

My doubt however, is that if it is allowed to switch the integral and sum because it is the absolute value. Also I don't know if the series converges because k changes all the time

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: When are adding / integrating positive numbers and functions, the order in which you add doesn't change convergence, or the value when they converge. Check Fubini's theorem for the more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track

Just for the justification of the 
  switch of the summation to the $p-$power and the integral you  can do this:

> $$\int |u|^p=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int_{m}^{m+1}|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}1_{[k,k+1)}|^p$$ $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^p}$$

So the function is in $L^p$ if and only if $p>1$

Comment: There are no errors in his argument. He just took absolute value first, then switched summation and integral, while you split the integral first, and then evaluated each integral. Just two different ways to see the same computation.

Comment: @conditionalMethod  the summation is in the p-power so i don't think you can switch the integral and summation that easily..here it can be done since the intervals in the indicator functions are disjoint,but in general you cannot...it he splited the integral then he has to mention that.

Comment: That is what he did. It is not an error, only that you didn't understand and he didn't explain what he did. In his line of computation he doesn't need to split the integral.

Comment: @conditionalMethod i have already edited my answer..